# Slimming Docker Image for Python Application

Tags: python, docker

i developed an python application that should run in a docker container. Everything went pretty well, both container and application are running perfectly. The thing is, that i just tried to get the docker container run for the first time. From now on, i want to improve my docker image. Right now i want to reduce the size of the image by deleting unneccasary dependencies. My Dockerfile is looking like this now:

```
###############################################################
# Use the Ubuntu 16.04 as a base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

###############################################################
# Update the dependencies in the image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8


###############################################################
# Install necessary overall dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3-dev \
python3-pip \
vim \
build-essential \
zlib1g-dev \ \
gfortran \
libblas-dev \
liblapack-dev \
libatlas-base-dev \
libzmq3-dev \
pkg-config \
libffi-dev \
libxml2 \
libxml2-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libcairo-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/likb/apt/lists/*

###############################################################
# Install necessary Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install numpy==1.16.1
RUN pip3 install scipy
RUN pip3 install cython
RUN pip3 install pyzmq==17.0.0
RUN pip3 install utm
RUN pip3 install python-igraph==0.7.1post6
RUN pip3 install matplotlib==3.0.2
RUN pip3 install cycler==0.10.0
RUN pip3 install dill==0.2.8.2
RUN pip3 install kiwisolver==1.0.1
RUN pip3 install pyparsing==2.3.0
RUN pip3 install pyreadline==2.1
RUN pip3 install python-dateutil==2.7.5
RUN pip3 install scikit-learn==0.20.2
RUN pip3 install six==1.12.0
RUN pip3 install sklearn==0.0
```

My docker image has a size of 1GB and it is just for a python application. I tried to reduce the size by not adding Ubuntu as a image and just work with an python base image. Everytime i use another base image i get errors that libraries or dependencies are not found. 
Perhaps you have some tips and tricks for me how to slim down this python image.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way docker builds an image is by layers. So every command (be it RUN or something else) in your Dockerfile represents a new layer.

A good way i have found to reduce image size is by minimizing the amount of layers in the Dockerfile. In your case a good place to start would probably be to include the following line:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install locales
```

into:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip \
    vim \
    build-essential \
    zlib1g-dev \ \
    gfortran \
    libblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libzmq3-dev \
    pkg-config \
    libffi-dev \
    libxml2 \
    libxml2-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libcairo-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/likb/apt/lists/*
```

this would make sure that when you delete /var/likb/apt/lists/* at the end of your RUN command, there are no layers already containing those lists before it.

Also since you are only looking to execute a python script, it might be worth looking for a smaller base image, since there are a lot of functionalities in ubuntu:16.04 that you are not using. You could, for instance, use the official python image python:$version.

Comment: Sounds like a good starting point for me, thanks! Whenever i try a Python image as a base image i get issues with installing the dependencies. It seems like that the python image is missing a few dependecies that i need.

Comment: Have a look at what the base is for the python image, usually it says something like alpine or stretch. This indicates the os type its build on, which in turn affects which packagemanager (like apt) you need.

Answer (score -1):

To improve your docker image, reduce the image size, reduce number of layers and install/uninstall in one layer.

```sh
###############################################################
# Use the Ubuntu 16.04 as a base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

###############################################################
# Update the dependencies in the image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8


###############################################################
# Install necessary overall dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3-dev \
python3-pip \
vim \
build-essential \
zlib1g-dev \ \
gfortran \
libblas-dev \
liblapack-dev \
libatlas-base-dev \
libzmq3-dev \
pkg-config \
libffi-dev \
libxml2 \
libxml2-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libcairo-dev \
\
\
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip \
&& pip3 install numpy==1.16.1 \
&& pip3 install scipy \
&& pip3 install cython \
&& pip3 install pyzmq==17.0.0 \
&& pip3 install utm \
&& pip3 install python-igraph==0.7.1post6 \
&& pip3 install matplotlib==3.0.2 \
&& pip3 install cycler==0.10.0 \
&& pip3 install dill==0.2.8.2 \
&& pip3 install kiwisolver==1.0.1 \
&& pip3 install pyparsing==2.3.0 \
&& pip3 install pyreadline==2.1 \
&& pip3 install python-dateutil==2.7.5 \
&& pip3 install scikit-learn==0.20.2 \
&& pip3 install six==1.12.0 \
&& pip3 install sklearn==0.0 \
\
\
&& apt-get remove -y \
python3-dev \
python3-pip \
vim \
build-essential \
zlib1g-dev \ \
gfortran \
libblas-dev \
liblapack-dev \
libatlas-base-dev \
libzmq3-dev \
pkg-config \
libffi-dev \
libxml2 \
libxml2-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libcairo-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/likb/apt/lists/* \
```

another approach is using docker multistage builder approach and installing python package in different directory,

```sh
###############################################################
# Use the Ubuntu 16.04 as a base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04 as sourceImage

###############################################################
# Update the dependencies in the image
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install locales
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8


###############################################################
# Install necessary overall dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
python3-dev \
python3-pip \
vim \
build-essential \
zlib1g-dev \ \
gfortran \
libblas-dev \
liblapack-dev \
libatlas-base-dev \
libzmq3-dev \
pkg-config \
libffi-dev \
libxml2 \
libxml2-dev \
zlib1g-dev \
libcairo-dev \
&& rm -rf /var/likb/apt/lists/*

###############################################################
# Install necessary Python dependencies
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   numpy==1.16.1 
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   scipy
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   cython
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   pyzmq==17.0.0
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   utm
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   python-igraph==0.7.1post6
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   matplotlib==3.0.2
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   cycler==0.10.0
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   dill==0.2.8.2
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   kiwisolver==1.0.1
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   pyparsing==2.3.0
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   pyreadline==2.1
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   python-dateutil==2.7.5
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   scikit-learn==0.20.2
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   six==1.12.0
RUN pip3 install --install-option="--prefix=/opt/pip-packages"   sklearn==0.0



FROM ubuntu:16.04 
RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/python-packages

COPY --from=sourceImage /opt/pip-packages/ /opt/python-packages

#### install system required packages, if needed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
vim \
gfortran \
pkg-config \
libxml2 \
&& rm -rf /var/likb/apt/lists/*
```